# How can i take a UITabbar in a viewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitabbar

If i go straight to the point then my problem is i have an UIViewController with two button.

1. Button One --(onclick must navigate to)--->`UITabbarController` with 4 `UITabbar` item or i can take a `UITabbar` in my new `UIViewController`;
2. Button Two --(OnClick must navigate to)--->`UITabbarController` where first `tabbaritem` will contain containing `UITableView` or or i can take a `UITabbar` in my new `UIViewController` where first `TabbarItem` will contain a `UITableView`.

How can i make this??? sample code will more helpful neither suggestion. if you need any clarification please do not hesitate to ask.

With Best Regards
Emon

Comment: @user427969 no, i am not using storyboard.

Comment: what did you try ??? try build it using storyboard :)

Comment: no i can not use storyboard.i have to make it pro grammatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to have a NavigationController if you want another view controller to be pushed on when you click a button. The steps you would need to do are the following

1. Start with a MasterDetail app on iPhone
2. In the xib file, put your buttons and wire them up to the correct methods
3. In the view did appear of the view controller have the following code

   ```
   self.tbc1 = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
   self.tbc2 = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];


   UIViewController *tbc1vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
   UIViewController *tbc1vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
   UIViewController *tbc1vc3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

   UITableViewController *tbc2vc1 = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
   UIViewController *tbc2vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
   UIViewController *tbc2vc3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

   [self.tbc1 setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tbc1vc1,tbc1vc2,tbc1vc3, nil]];
   [self.tbc1 setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tbc2vc1,tbc2vc2,tbc2vc3, nil]];
   ```
4. Ofcourse you have to have properties defined for tbc1 adn tbc2 in your view controller.
5. In the app delegate do the following

   ```
       self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

   ViewController *myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
   self.viewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
   self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
   ```
6. Change the UIViewController in the .h file to UINavigationController like

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *viewController;
   ```
7. Have the two buttons and wire it to the following methods

   ```
   -(IBAction)tbc1Clicked{
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.tbc1 animated:YES];
   }

   -(IBAction)tbc2Clicked{
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.tbc2 animated:YES];
   }
   ```

Comment: at first thanks for your answer.i can understand your solution but there is two problems,firstly i cannot take masterdetail app now.secondly i can not take any nib in this application. so is there any alternate option if i use a empty application???

Comment: Explain where are you now in your current app and I can walk you from there.

Comment: i am at initial state unfortunate but true...i have made my empty application where in app delegate i have taken a uiviewcontroller as a rootviewcontroler which is containing my two buttons... when i will click on first button it will navigate(must navigate not modal) me to another controller which will contain 4 uitabbar items with navigation bar.now when will click on second button it will move to another controller of uitabbar items.is it clear?

Comment: Your app delegate should have a navigation controller, if you want other view controllers to easily come on top of it. I will edit the answer to show what you need to do

Comment: Thanks..please do it...i stuck on it.

Comment: i have done it already but i need next portion after clicking the buttons.

Comment: Emon, I will edit the answer, but looks like you have to get a good beginner book and read it, or listen to all the WWDC videos or Stanford videos. You owe it to yourself to understand the basics

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20969/discussion-between-emon-and-srikanth)